# Jenkins permission denied - how to change rights from IntelliJ Idea and Windows?

Tags: windows, bash, git, jenkins

I have a `Jenkinsfile` with the following stage executing a bash (`sh`) script:

```
stage('Prepare') {
    sh 'cd ./bin && ./prepare.sh'
}
```

The Jenkins fails the stage producing an error:

> ```
> 14:27:16  + cd ./bin
> 14:27:16  + ./prepare.sh
> 14:27:16  /data/jenkins/workspace/repo_J_tmp/durable-8864902e/script.sh: line 1: ./prepare.sh: Permission denied
> ```

I use IntelliJ Idea and Windows. How to change and push the rights?

The command `chmod=+x ./bin/prepare.sh` in Git Bash is not registered as a change, so there is nothing to commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is needed to use `git --update-index` with Git Bash and then perform the commit through the Windows command line.

The sequence of commands follows (assuming Git Bash is installed):

```
PS C:\Development\repo> bash
user@DESKTOP-ABCDEFG:/mnt/c/Development/repo$ git update-index --chmod=+x ./docs/prepare.sh
user@DESKTOP-ABCDEFG:/mnt/c/Development/repo$ exit
PS C:\Development\repo> git commit -m"Executable Script"
```

The commit is ready to be pushed (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> or `git push`).

Also, note the line separator must be `LR`: Unix and MacOS compatible (`\n`), otherwise `/usr/bin/env: ‘bash\r’: No such file or directory` shows as an error.